# Simple jQuery toggle on icon in heading

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have a very simple jQuery toggle with minimal code. Issue is that I only want the toggle behaviour applied to the toggle symbol that is applied as background CSS image to the p element, positioned to the far right. Right now it applies to the whole element. The title is a hyperlink, so when it's clicked on, it starts to perform the toggle before going to the new URL.

**HTML Code** is as such:

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p class="accordion-toggle dormantState"><a href="http://google.com">Q ANZAC 100</a></p>
      <div class="accordion-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="accordion-toggle dormantState"><a href="http://google.com">Business studio</a></p>
      <div class="accordion-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="accordion-toggle dormantState"><a href="http://google.com">The Edge</a></p>
      <div class="accordion-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer; width: 80%; }
.activeState { background-image: url(../img/minus-icon.png)!important; background-position: right center; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
.dormantState { background-image: url(../img/plus-icon.png); background-position: right center; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
.accordion-content {display: none; border: 1px solid: #ccc; width: 70%; }
```

**JS:**

```
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.otherSites').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

    $('.accordion-toggle').removeClass('activeState');
    if($(this).parent().find('.accordion-content').css('display')=='none'){
       $(this).addClass('activeState');
    }

      //Expand or collapse this panel
      $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
  });
```

I have tried to create a span tag after the closing of the  tag and apply the accordian toggle classes to it as well as refactor my JS code (using .parent syntax) but I think I'm just making it too complicated and digging a hole for myself. Is there a simple solution to this by just tweaking the JS code?

Comment: So you want to navigate to new `URL` when you click on anchor and also toggle its contents?

Comment: Yes, Mr Rao. That's right. I want the clickable area for the toggle behaviour to be isolated to the toggle +/- icon only.

Comment: If new `URL` is getting opened, then what's use of toggling.. The page changes right?

Comment: Yes, but the page does not change quick enough, the toggle opens before the page opens.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal DEMO for this?? A `jsfiddle` will be good enough!!

Comment: Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/coolwebs/jewr2t5b/1/ and also I've been working within a GitHub branch here https://rawgit.com/SLQ-web/Packery-Mockup-SLQ-Homepage/Ryan's-Responsive-Spec/html/prototype-base.html

Comment: Ok.. Got your point now.. Isn't it possible to use `font-awesome.css` specially for displaying icons? instead of attaching image.. Just asking!!

Comment: Yes @GuruprasadRao, I could use font-awesome, but that's not really the point. Page has heaps of external scripts being called as it is. So many comments on this page now, did you want to start a conversation instead?

Comment: Sure.. That will be good.. I am ready to help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve this myself. Had to rearrange code substantially. Ditched using classes with image backgrounds and made use of span elements.

HTML code:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <p class="accordion-toggle dormantState"><a href="http://qanzac100.slq.qld.gov.au">Q ANZAC 100</a><span class="toggleIcon">+</span></p>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="accordion-toggle dormantState"><a href="#">Business studio</a><span class="toggleIcon">+</span></p>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="accordion-toggle dormantState"><a href="http://edgeqld.org.au/">The Edge</a><span class="toggleIcon">+</span></p>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
</ul>
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('.otherSites').find('.accordion-toggle span').click(function(){

  //Expand or collapse this panel
  $(this.parentNode).next().slideToggle('fast');

    // Determine if it's open or closed
    var toggleState = $(this).html();
    if (toggleState=="+") {
        $(this).html("-");
    } else if (toggleState=="-") {
        $(this).html("+")
    }

  //Hide the other panels
  $(".accordion-content").not($(this.parentNode).next()).slideUp('fast');

    //Find change the icon of any open panels back to closed
    if($('.otherSites').find('.accordion-content span').html("-")){
        console.log("make all other toggles go to +");
        $(".toggleIcon").not($(this)).html("+")
    }
});
});
```

Not 100% happy with the JS code and having to give the span element a class, but it does the job.